# difference between Gridview element and other table element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dom, gridview

I'm trying to access DOM element using Jquery in an ASP.NET page.
The thing is that when ASP.NET page get transformed to pure HTML,it see both `Gridview` control and other `table` like controls like `checklistbox` as `table`.

Is there any way that can distinguished between `Gridview` and other `table` like controls?

Comment: You can distinguish it with the respective id of each control.

Comment: @DineshPrajapati i know that , but i want to be able to loop through all controls and find gridview without knowing the id

Comment: You can give different class to the controls for identifying them, or you can give custom attribute "data-yourcustomname" (like data-controltype="table") to identify your control. You can then check that attribute value to identify the control.

Comment: @DineshPrajapati thanks for the replay , yeah i already tried custom attribute and its working , but i was wondering is there any way that i can distinguished it with other controls?

Comment: If you dont want to use customattribute or class than other way around can be to construct your id to include your control identification. Like in case of gridview you can give id "gridviewsomething" so forth and so on. This way you can than check startwith control name to identify the control. This way you will need not to rely on custom attribute.